# Best way to loop through files

Tags: python

I am working in python to loop through roughly 1,000 files in a folder. I've been trying to come up with function and for loops but I keep getting stuck. I am somewhat of a beginner so it is somewhat difficult. My goal is to open one file, read it for about 1,000 x,y,z coordinates. this is where I started and if you have any pointers on where to continue, or functions to use I would appreciate it!

```
import os
import glob

DIRECTORY = os.chdir("C:\Py Practice\Files")

for filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    f = open(filename)
```

Comment: I would open the file using `with open(filename, 'r') as fin:`  also you don't need to change folder, so the `os.chdir` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Please use the example below (I've added some short explanation for each line), hopefully this will help you :)

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isfile

path = r"C:\Py Practice\Files"
for filename in listdir(path):  # iterates over all the files in 'path'
    full_path = join(path, filename)  # joins the path with the filename
    if isfile(full_path):  # validate that it is a file
        with open(full_path) as f:  # open the file
            print(f.read())  # print the file's contents
```

Note that this isn't recursive (in that case I would use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html))

Answer (score -1):

glob module is better. You should also create file object using **with** keyword.

```
 import glob
    
    # list all files including subfolders
    files = glob.glob('"C:/Py Practice/Files"/**/*.txt', recursive=True)
    
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
            f.read()
```

Comment: thank you! do you have a suggestion on what to use to get the strings on the lines following "atoms"? So far I was able to use "for line in files:" and find the atoms string in each